# Adding post_category to PHP XMLRPC

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to figure out how to add post_category to a new post created by XMLRPC using "PHPXMLRPC".

I have the following code:

```
$message = new xmlrpcmsg(
        $function_name, 
        array(
            new xmlrpcval(0, "int"), 
            new xmlrpcval($username, "string"), 
            new xmlrpcval($password, "string"), 
            new xmlrpcval(
                array(
                    "post_type" => new xmlrpcval("post", "string"),
                    "post_status" => new xmlrpcval("publish", "string"),
                    "post_title" => new xmlrpcval($article_title, "string"),
                    "post_category" => new xmlrpcval(array( 'Cars' => 12 ),"int"),
                    "post_author" => new xmlrpcval(1, "int"),
                    "post_content" => new xmlrpcval($new_article, "string")
                    ), 
                "struct"
                )
            )
        );
```

For "post_category" I've tried a large variety of things:

```
                    "post_category" => new xmlrpcval('Cars'),"int"),
                    "post_category" => new xmlrpcval('Cars'),"string"),
                    "post_category" => new xmlrpcval(array( 'Cars' => 12 ),"array"),
                    "post_category" => new xmlrpcval(array( 'Cars' => 12 ),"int"),
                    "post_category" => new xmlrpcval(12),"int"),
```

And every other variation I can think of. Can anyone help me with adding the category (preferably by NAME, not ID, as the ID will be unknown)?

Comment: Check this answer, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/171961 It appears that when using `post_category`, you can only specify numeric IDs, but check the method mentioned at the end, using `terms_names` you should also be able to specify them via name.

Comment: @04FS I tried forever, I even tried to use that post. Sadly, I kept getting a "serialized data" error. Likely caused by faulty 'new xmlrpcval' formatting in an array. I tried for hours and eventually am testing a different function for posting.

Comment: "post_category" => new xmlrpcval('Cars',"int"), - this creates an integer value, 0;
"post_category" => new xmlrpcval('Cars',"string"), - this creates a string value;
"post_category" => new xmlrpcval(array( 'Cars' => 12 ),"array"), - this is not good either, if you want to create a named-array you should use "struct" instead of "array", and wrap 12 in an int xmlrpcval;
"post_category" => new xmlrpcval(array( 'Cars' => 12 ),"int"),  - this creates an integer value, 0;
"post_category" => new xmlrpcval(12,"int"), - this creates an integer value, 12. You are better off with PhpXmlRpc\Encoder